# Pug/ Jade - input is a self closing element: <input/> but contains nested content?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I want to create the html like this:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="hidden" checked="" value="Visible"> Visible
</label>
```

Pug/ Jade:

```
label.radio-inline
    input(type="radio", name="hidden", value="0", checked="") Visible
```

But I get an error:

> input is a self closing element:  but contains nested content.

What does it mean? How I can fix this?

Comment: `<input>` element can't contain anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that using Jade / Pug. The first way is to use a pipe char (which requires a new line):

```
input
  | text
```

The second way is to use tag interpolation (and you can stay on the same line):

```
#[input] text
```

So an alternative Jethro's answer would be:

```
label.radio-inline
  #[input(type='radio', name='hidden', value=0, checked='')] Visible
```

Note that you can even do:

```
 label #[input] text
```

Which will generate:

```html
<label>
  <input/> text 
</label>
```

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to it like this:

```
label.radio-inline
  input(type='radio', name='hidden', value=0, checked='')
  | Visible
```

Putting `Visible` on the same line as `input`, makes pug interpret it as the inner HTML of the `input` element.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's nonsense to put the `input` inside the `label` tag, or no? You could just do

```
label(for="ya") Visible
input(id="ya", type="radio", name="hidden", value=0, checked="")
```

That gives you a perfectly labeled radio button in accord with modern [web standards](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp).

Comment: Could, although that's not the OPs requirement. Note as well that your link explicitly states "Tip: A label can be bound to an element either by using the "for" attribute, or by placing the element inside the <label> element."

Comment: Fair enough, I overlooked that. Thanks! From a semantic perspective I'd not use that.

Comment: I still get that error `input#first_name.form-control.input-sm.floatlabel(type="text", name="first_name", placeholder="First Name")`